# Recover source code from published expo app

Tags: reactjs, expo

Is there any way to recover source code from published expo app recently i was hacked and my source code got encrypted by the hackers with the new variant of djvu with an online key and i really need the source code and i have published it to expo is there any way?

Comment: if you have published, maybe you have a copy it your code editor or somewhere already. also, please give this a read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The copy is encrypted by the virus